# Cant get android's autocomplete working with server response

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, android-volley

So I have been trying to add a suggestion list for my auto-complete text view in android. I have added an onClickListener to it. Whenever onCLick is triggered. I have created an adapter and a data structure called mylist (ArrayList). I can't see any error but at the same time the autocomplete feature is not working. I am pretty sure there is some small glitch I am unable to find. Please let me know where am I going wrong. TIA.

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        user_input = findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        Log.i("here", "something");
        user_input.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i("here", "something");
                String symbol_auto = String.valueOf(user_input.getText());
                String company_auto = "http://us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/autocomplete/"+symbol_auto;
                requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                JsonArrayRequest arrayreq = new JsonArrayRequest(company_auto+symbol_auto,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                            // Takes the response from the JSON request
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonobj = response.getJSONObject(0);
                                    data = jsonobj.getString("Name");
                                    mylist.add(data);
                                    Log.i("here", data);
                                    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, mylist);
                                    user_input.setThreshold(1);
                                    user_input.setAdapter(adapter);
                                }
                                // Try and catch are included to handle any errors due to JSON
                                catch (JSONException e) {
                                    // If an error occurs, this prints the error to the log
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        // The final parameter overrides the method onErrorResponse() and passes VolleyError
                        //as a parameter
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                            }
                        }
                );
                // Adds the JSON array request "arrayreq" to the request queue
                requestQueue.add(arrayreq);
            }
        });
    }
```

I have tried adding elements to myList manually and it works like charm but the dropdown list just doesnt appear once I try adding it after querying to my back-end. My back-end is working fine. I have verified.

Comment: are you sure that your server is working?  did you receive response from your server? what is the data?

Comment: I altered the url for this question inorder to prevent multiple visits to server (its on free tier of AWS) but yeah the url is working. The symbol_auto should be getting the symbol from the autocompletetextview after each event. I manually typed the url with appended parameter and it works fine. It returns a  JSON object.

Comment: put the json object in your question

Comment: [{"Symbol":"ABC","Name":"AmerisourceBergen Corp","Exchange":"NYSE"},{"Symbol":"ABC","Name":"AmerisourceBergen Corp","Exchange":"BATS Trading Inc"},{"Symbol":"ABCB","Name":"Ameris Bancorp","Exchange":"NASDAQ"}]

Comment: @diegoveloper This is the response for abc as the parameter

Comment: do you receive any error log ?  what is the result of this :  Log.i("here", data);    ?

Comment: do you want to put only the first element in your autocomplete or do you want to put the complete array?

Comment: @diegoveloper it seems the code is not reaching Log.i("here", data); Now I see E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length as the error

Comment: so inside `onItemClick` you call web API? what for?

Comment: @diegoveloper I would want the complete. I intend on looping through the entire object to extract necessary data

Comment: @pskink I did that so that API could return me back a json object which I could parse in order to get relevant data, store that data into mylist so that it appears in the autotextcompleteview

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830

Comment: @pskink I have chosen to use Volley

Comment: and? does it change anything? just make sync request inside `runQuery` method, did you run my code? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: @pskink I dont know how filterQueryProvider works. I need to understand your code first. I have invested 2 days already in Volley. SO thought of debugging it first. Hope you understand.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FilterQueryProvider.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over your elements and add each one to your list, then set the adapter.

```
 new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                        // Takes the response from the JSON request
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            try {
                                 mylist = new ArrayList();   
                                for (int i = 0; i< response.length(); i++){
                                    JSONObject jsonobj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String value = jsonobj.getString("Name");
                                    mylist.add(value);
                                    Log.i("here", value);
                                }

                                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, mylist);
                                user_input.setThreshold(1);
                                user_input.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                            // Try and catch are included to handle any errors due to JSON
                            catch (JSONException e) {
                                // If an error occurs, this prints the error to the log
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

**UPDATE - use OnClickListener to fire the event**

```
user_input.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     Log.i("here", "something");
            String symbol_auto = String.valueOf(user_input.getText());
            String company_auto = "http://us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/autocomplete/"+symbol_auto;
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            JsonArrayRequest arrayreq = new JsonArrayRequest(company_auto+symbol_auto,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                        // Takes the response from the JSON request
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            try {
                                 mylist = new ArrayList();   
                                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
                                    JSONObject jsonobj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String value = jsonobj.getString("Name");
                                    mylist.add(value);
                                    Log.i("here", value);
                                }

                                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, mylist);
                                user_input.setThreshold(1);
                                user_input.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                            // Try and catch are included to handle any errors due to JSON
                            catch (JSONException e) {
                                // If an error occurs, this prints the error to the log
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    // The final parameter overrides the method onErrorResponse() and passes VolleyError
                    //as a parameter
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                        }
                    }
            );
            // Adds the JSON array request "arrayreq" to the request queue
            requestQueue.add(arrayreq);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I get an error stating response expected boolean not int. length() returns int, right ?

Comment: Still not getting any response from the server. I do see E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length when I completely empty my autocomplete.

Comment: Its not entering user_input.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {   Because on entering debug mode, I cant find my log.d() but I wonder why because on my phone (not using an emulator) I am tapping on autocomplete to start the event. Really confused.

Comment: @jyotirmayaojha do you know what `OnItemClickListene` is for?

Comment: Its used when an item in a particular adapter view is clicked. I am really sorry if I am wasting your time but I started android dev two days back.

Comment: I updated my answer, use onclicklistener to fire the event and onItemClickListener to get which item of the autocompletextview was clicked